# Iterate through all the op attribute in Antlr4

Tags: c#, antlr4

Im trying to iterate through all the op attribute in my Visitor class.

Here is my Grammar:

```
where: expression ( op=( AND | OR ) expressions)* EOF;
```

The string I am trying to parse is:

```
string str = "Name = 'John Doe' AND Age = 20 OR Age = 30";
```

For my Visitor class, I have a simple override method:

```
public override object VisitWhere([NotNull] WhereContext context)
{
    string operator = context.op.Text;
    return base.VisitWhere(context);
}
```

After parsing the string, the operator variable returns the last occurrence of the op attribute which is 'OR'. How do I get the 'AND'?

Answer (score 0):

If a rule or token appears multiple times in a rule it will be represented as an array in the associated context. In your case you should have an array `context.op[]`. Such arrays or the simple `op` property are only convenience means to access the child list. If you want full access to everything that was parsed in a rule look at the children of that context.